# Spring Boot JMS MarshallingMessageConverter in replies

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jms

I've a JMS listener similar to the one done here:

[Synchronous Message send and receive using JMS template and Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146057/synchronous-message-send-and-receive-using-jms-template-and-spring-boot)

It receives a XML payload. But different from that one, I want to also return a reply. If I return a String, it works ok, but as I'm doing with the message payload, I want to return a JAXB object.

However, if I return a Message, Spring tries to convert the object using the SimpleMessageConverter.

How can I configure the MarshallingMessageConverter to be used when converting the reply payload?

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure the DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory's message converter.

But what is weird, I already have a MarshallingMessageConverter there for DefaultMessageHandlerMethodFactory and JmsMessagingTemplate, and it's from another Java package (org.springframework.messaging.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter).

```
@Bean
public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> jmsListenerFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer)
{
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
    factory.setErrorHandler(errorHandler());
    factory.setMessageConverter(jmsMarshallingMessageConverter());  // !!!!

    configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);

    return factory;
}

@Bean
public org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter jmsMarshallingMessageConverter()
{
    Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = marshaller();

    org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter converter =
        new org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MarshallingMessageConverter();
    converter.setMarshaller(marshaller);
    converter.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
    converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);

    return converter;
}
```